# How to add comments to the side of text body?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-position, absolute

I am trying to add a comment section to the **side** of an article's text. I would like it to behave like the comments in google docs (see image). [image: Google Docs Comment example]

Google docs is using absolute position, but I am wondering how to align the div with selected text in the body. Also, is there a better way to do this using modern css than computing the pixel position for each comment box?

I have looked into flex box, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pin a div to a piece of text, which is essentially what is needed.

EDIT:
I am currently using something like this, but the trouble is calculating the top px value relative to a line of text.

```
<div style={{position: "absolute", top: "40px", left: "1200px", border: "solid"}}>
    Test comment.
</div>
```

Comment: provide code of what you have tried.  Look into flexbox

Comment: I added what I have tried. Another complication is that even though the comment div is inside a flexbox(which contains the body text and other divs), the px values for the comment box are relative to the window, not the containing flexbox.